# How to get the image icons in the listview using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get the image icons in a listview dynamically. If i've 5 images like 0.png to 4.png and i've 5 lists in listview. Before the list name i want to display the images as icons in the listview dynamically using jquery.

```
$("#list").append('<li><a href="#chapter" id="' + order + '"><img src="icons/"' + imageurl + ' id="imageURL"/>' + section + '  </a> </li>');
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did the above code not worked for you?

Comment: `id` should be unique in a document, all your images will have same id, so probably you should remove it

Comment: here i mentioned the code is for appending html tags.how to display multiple images icons in a listview.

Comment: where do you want to place the images? can make a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2vY7T/5/ i want to place the images in the listview before the names in the list

Comment: add image link to parent tag and read it. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ChsYv/

Comment: in this way we'll get without adding img tag to xml like if i want to display images in some folder in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution..For creating the images as icons in the listview dynamically..

```
$('#').load(file, function (data) {
   var txt = $(data).find('p').text();
   var image = $(data).find('img');
   var pic = $(data).find('img').attr('src');
   var picture = '<img src="'+ pic +'" style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>';
$("#content_list").append('<li><a href="#" class="style1"  file="' + file + '">'+ picture +'<h2>' + content + ' </h2><p class="description">' + txt + '</p></a></li> ');
```